# Undo deleted row on DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, undo

I have a DataGridView that imports data from an Excel file. And on the form, it has a delete button wherein if a row is selected from the DataGridView table then the delete button is clicked, the row selected is deleted.

Is there a way to 'undo' the deletion? I need to make a functioning undo button.

Comment: No, it's not magic.  You have to code all that yourself.  Store the row before you delete it, then add it back with the undo functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView has a event called UserDeletingRow, coming before the row is actually deleted, allowing you to cancel the delete process.

```
private void dgv1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show("Really delete ?", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [DataGridView.UserDeletingRow Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow) to save the row values before the row is deleted and then insert a new row with the saved values on undo. Or just hide the row and un-hide it on undo.

If you use `DataTable` for the `DataGridView.DataSource`, then you can probably save the `DataRow` in the `DataGridView.UserDeletingRow` event with something like

```
lastDeletedDataRow = e.Row.DataBoundItem as DataRow;
```

and then try `lastDeletedDataRow.SetModified();` on undo.

Comment: how to retrieve last deleted row in c#